# How can I setup only contribution page in dual language

Tags: contribution-page

I want to setup only a contribution page in two languages: English and Spanish. However, civicrm default language should be English. User should be able to select their preferred language to see the contribution page.

Is this achievable, any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable. First. Is your website multilingual, have you got it for two languages? What CMS platform are you on?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, CMS is Drupal 7 and it is not multilingual.

Comment: In Administer CiviCRM - Localization, add language of choice. This changes the Profile layout so that you see a green icon next to the label. Click on the green icon and you will then be able to have the label in your first language, then in your second language (and so on if more languages). Option groups are done the same way - in fact most of the text is like this. The way I have it setup is my website is multilingual so it works nicely. In the past I used to create two Events (one in English one in French) say i was doing an event registration.